# html frozen at Jquery dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am developing a client side application where I am using a jquery confirm dialog box. It asks for user confirmation and if user selects 'Yes' it should close the dialog box and then delete the items in a table. However, what I am seeing is (if user selects 'Yes'), application is busy deleting the table items and UI is frozen with dialog confirm box. Is there any way I can get intended response from this code? (means close the confirm-dialog and then proceed with delete action). 
Note: this is not in any browser; I am using IE component to load the html in client side widget.

```
$('<div title="Confirm" class="cfmDialog" />')
        .html('<span style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>' + "Are you sure you want to delete all items in table?")

        // Define the Dialog and its properties.
        .dialog({
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            title: "Delete table items",
            height: 150,
            width: 300,
            buttons: {
                "Yes": function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    deleteTableItems();
                },
                "No": function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Fix `deleteTableItems()` so it doesn't block the browser. The display isn't updated until functions return to the main event loop.

Comment: What does deleteTableItems() function do?

Comment: @Barmar , Since I have "$(this).dialog('close'); " before deleteTableItems(); function I thought this would close dialog box first?

Comment: @Adam Baranyai, it uses an API service to delete items from a table. (that is working as expected).

Comment: @Nik closing a dialogue just hides it in the DOM. But DOM changes are not rendered until all functions end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run `deleteTableItems()` after a timeout:

```
"Yes": function() {
    $(this).dialog("close");
    setTimeout(deleteTableItems, 1);
},
```

But this will still freeze the browser while the function runs, it will just allow the dialog to close first. The best solution is to fix `deleteTableItems` so it operates asynchronously.